# Modify a struct while iterating over an Iterable in the struct

Tags: rust

I am implementing a rolling prime sieve in Rust. The struct looks like this:

```rust
struct Sieve {
    window_index: u32,
    window_size: u32,
    board: BitVec,
    primes: Vec<u32>,
}
```

There is a moving 'window' in which prime multiples are marked on a board of size `window_size`, and any numbers encountered that are unmarked are known to be prime.

When the window is moved, the new board needs to be re-initialized with all the multiples of the previously discovered primes marked.

```rust
let square_optimization = (self.window_index + self.window_size).integer_sqrt();
for &prime in self.primes.iter().filter(|&&p| p < square_optimization) {
    let remainder = self.window_index % prime;
    let start_prime = if remainder > 0 { self.window_index + prime - remainder } else { remainder };
    if start_prime > self.window_index + self.window_size { return; }

    for i in (start_prime % self.window_size..self.window_size).step_by(prime as usize) {
        self.board.set(i as usize, true)
    }
}
```

The exact logic doesn't matter, however you can see that there is an immutable borrow of `self.primes` and a mutable borrow of `self.board`. The compiler is happy. The problem appears when extracting the logic into a function:

```rust
fn mark_multiples(&mut self, prime: u32) {
    let remainder = self.window_index % prime;
    let start_prime = if remainder > 0 { self.window_index + prime - remainder } else { remainder };
    if start_prime > self.window_index + self.window_size { return; }

    for i in (start_prime % self.window_size..self.window_size).step_by(prime as usize) {
        self.board.set(i as usize, true)
    }
}

fn compute_chunk(&mut self) {
    let square_optimization = (self.window_index + self.window_size).integer_sqrt();
    for &prime in self.primes.iter().filter(|&&p| p < square_optimization) {
        self.mark_multiples(prime)
    }

    // do work
}
```

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/lib.rs:54:13
   |
53 |         for &prime in self.primes.iter().filter(|&&p| p < square_optimization) {
   |                       --------------------------------------------------------
   |                       |
   |                       immutable borrow occurs here
   |                       immutable borrow later used here
54 |             self.mark_multiples(prime)
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

Why does the borrow checker get confused here? Is `self` not mutably borrowed in the first case?

Comment: Are you sure it's the borrow checker who got confused? ;)

Comment: I haven't come across a language in which method extraction doesn't "just work" but being new to rust, no, I'm not sure.

Comment: `mark_multiples` mutably borrows the entirety of `self`, but `prime` is also immutably borrowed *from* self. What would happen to `prime` if the implementation of `mark_multiples` decided to replace `self` and drop the original version? Now, *you* know that your function doesn't do this, but the compiler doesn't!

Comment: Rust references work like read-write locks. You either exclusively acquire (`&mut`) it mutably, or you acquire a shared lock (`&`) immutably. Exclusive and shared can't happen simultaneously.

Comment: @arlyon, method extraction indeed does *not* “just work” in Rust, because the borrow checker works separately in each function, only considering the signature for their interfaces. So you can extract functions, but if you pass them references to more than they actually touch, they may start to conflict where the mixed code didn't. This is very intentional, because it allows you to refactor the function bodies with confidence that you are not creating a conflict with code in some caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why?  Because `self.primes` borrowed immutably (because of [`Vec::iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter), i.e. the newly created iterator, [`Iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html) is referencing the vector which is owned by `self`) and while this is happening `mark_multiples` tries to borrow `self` as mutable.  The borrowing rules are simple and straightforward:

1. You could have arbitrary number of immutable borrows of an object at a given time, or
2. You could have a single mutable borrow of an object at a given time.

Thus, you cannot have a mutable borrow of `self`, while you still hold an immutable borrow of it, and that's exactly the reason why the compiler refuses to compile your code.

Why is this safety feature considered any good here?  If what you want would be allowed for you that would mean, you could potentially change the values of `self.primes` in the method `self.mark_multiples` while you iterate over it in `self.compute_chunk`.  You could easily run into referencing invalid memory locations!